# Why can't I save my model with a generic relation twice in Django?

Tags: django, save, generic-relations

I got a model TrackedItem with a generic relation linking to any model it is supposed to track.

If I do that:

```
t = TrackedItem(content_object=MyModel)
t.save()
t.save()
```

I get :

```
IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'")
```

Indeed, the first save has created an entry with "1" as a PK. But the second save should not insert, it should update.

How am I suppose to update a model I can't save twice?

With an ordinary model I can save as much as I want.

EDIT : it may be not related at all with generic relations.

I'm having a overrided save, and I call super in it, this way :

```
super(TrackedItem, self).save(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

if I do it this way, it works:

```
model.Model.save(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: What makes you think this has anything to do with the generic relation? Do you have a custom `save()` method on this model by any chance?

Comment: You are right, I'm using a custome 'save' :-) I'm going to add informations on the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is most likely because of wrong use of 'super'. It should be like this:

```
super(TrackedItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a DB transaction issue. Is there a [DB-Commit](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/) bewteen the two save calls? Maybe your View is under transaction.commit_on_sucess controll.

2 Possibilities:

```
  transaction.commit() # within transaction.commit_manually
```

or

```
  t.save(force_update=True) # 2nd save call
```

Comment: No, it's a very basic code, I'm not using commit anywhere. Plus, grepping the lib I use don't show me any "commit". I tried "force_update" but end up with "ValueError: Cannot force both insert and updating in model saving."

Comment: OK,then its porbably i failure within your custom save (like Botondus said). 

Have a look at your custom save written in the question. Their was a wrong 'self'.
it schould be in the form like:
super(TrackedItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)